# Как реализовать аналог примера background-clip linear-gradient и mix-blend-mode на SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Есть такой пример анимации

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #272727;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.oboi7.com/bd48c3217e4d770da198fdff5fb165a3c6c09cd2/devushki-odetta-annable-lica.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

.test-grad {
  font-size: 7vmax;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
  line-height: 2;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fff 50%, #272727 50%), linear-gradient(to top, #000 50%, #fff 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text, padding-box;
  color: transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  animation: gradient-top 3s linear infinite;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-position: top;
  transition: background-position 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes gradient-top {
  0% {
    background-position: bottom;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 50% 300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test-grad">Test gradient</div>
```

Как такое реализовать в SVG?

У кого-то может возникнуть вопрос ***`А чем не устраивает данная реализация?`***, проблема в том, что не работает в FF.

Запустите пример ниже в браузере Mozilla и будет понятно в чем проблема.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #272727;
}

.test-grad {
  font-size: 7vmax;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
  line-height: 2;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fff 50%, #272727 50%), linear-gradient(to top, #000 50%, #fff 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text, padding-box;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-grad">Test gradient</div>
```

Но если будет решение без `SVG` и что бы этот пример работал и на `FF` тоже хорошо....

Но есть решение для `FF`, но без `mix-blend-mode: multiply;`, не имею представления куда добавить `mix-blend-mode`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #272727;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.oboi7.com/bd48c3217e4d770da198fdff5fb165a3c6c09cd2/devushki-odetta-annable-lica.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

.wrapper {}

.test-grad {
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fff 50%, #27272700 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-position: top;
  animation: gradient-top 3s linear infinite;
}

.test-grad p {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 95px;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #272727 50%, #fff 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: gradient-top 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient-top {
  0% {
    background-position: bottom;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 50% 300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test-grad">
    <p>Test gradient</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рабочий, принятый вариант - `#3`
Первые два варианта не полностью соответствуют требованиям в вопросе.

Пояснения в комментариях кода.

**#1**.
Анимация начинается после клика по картинке.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1920 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >   
 
 <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton&display=swap');
    </style>
 
 <defs> 
   <mask id="msk1"> 
     <!-- показывает весь фон -->
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
  <!-- Текстовая маска вырезает надпись -->   
     <text x="1050" y="495" font-size="120px" font-family="'Anton'" font-weight="700" text-anchor="middle" fill="black"> Test gradient</text> 
   </mask>
 </defs>
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9F0b.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  />
     <!-- Чёрный прямоугольник с применением текстовой маски -->
   <rect x="0" y="380" width="1920" height="135" fill="black" mask="url(#msk1)" >
      <!-- анимация уменьшения, увеличения высоты прямоугольника -->
  <animate attributeName="height" dur="6s" values="135;0;0;135;135" begin="svg1.click" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </rect> 
 
</svg>
```

**#2.** Ещё один вариант с анимацией черно-белого текста

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1920 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >   
 
 <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton&display=swap');
    </style>
 
 <defs> 
   <mask id="msk1"> 
     <!-- показывает весь фон -->
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
  <!-- Текстовая маска вырезает надпись -->   
     <text x="1050" y="495" font-size="120px" font-family="'Anton'" font-weight="700" text-anchor="middle" fill="black"> Test gradient</text> 
   </mask> 
    <mask id="msk2"> 
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />   
   <rect x="0" y="380" width="1920" height="0" fill="black" >
     
  <animate attributeName="height" dur="6s" values="0;135;135;0;0" begin="svg1.click" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </rect>  
      <text x="1050" y="495" font-size="120px" font-family="'Anton'" font-weight="700" text-anchor="middle" fill="white"> Test gradient</text> 
    </mask>
 </defs>
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9F0b.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
     <!-- Чёрный прямоугольник с применением текстовой маски -->
   <rect x="0" y="380" width="1920" height="135" fill="black" mask="url(#msk2)"> 
      <!-- анимация уменьшения, увеличения высоты прямоугольника -->
   <animate attributeName="height" dur="6s" values="135;0;0;135;135" begin="svg1.click" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </rect> 
 
</svg>
```

**#3.** Вариант с применением `clipPath` и `mask`

`clipPath` вырезает чёрную надпись из чёрного прямоугольника
`mask` вырезает из чёрной полосы надпись, которая заполняется фоновой картинкой

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1920 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;">   
 
 <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton&display=swap');
    </style>
 
 <defs> 
   <mask id="msk1"> 
     <!-- показывает весь фон -->
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"  />
  <!-- Текстовая маска вырезает надпись -->   
     <text x="1050" y="495" font-size="120px" font-family="'Anton'" font-weight="700" text-anchor="middle" fill="black"> Test gradient</text> 
   </mask>
   
     <clipPath id="clip1"> 
        <text x="1050" y="495" font-size="120px" font-family="'Anton'" font-weight="700" text-anchor="middle" fill="black"> Test gradient</text> 
  
   </clipPath>
 </defs>
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9F0b.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  />
   
 <rect x="0" y="380" width="1920" height="135" fill="black" mask="url(#msk1)" >
     
  <animate attributeName="height" dur="4s" values="135;0;0;135;135"  repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 </rect> 
    <!-- здесь вырезается и анимируется чёрный цвет надписи -->
  <rect x="0" y="245" width="1920" height="135" fill="black" stroke="black" clip-path="url(#clip1)" >
    <animate attributeName="y" dur="4s" values="245;380;380;245;245"  repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 </rect> 
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Имеет право на жизнь, но не то...

Comment: @Air так и написал я в начале ответа, буду дальше искать, решение где-то рядом

Comment: Да я видел... Это просто мысли в слух...

Comment: @Air посмотри вариант #3 он ближе всех к твоему вопросу

Comment: Это не просто похоже, а точь-в-точь...